# Android: How to disable selection magnifier in ICS?

Tags: android, android-edittext

When selecting text in an EditText view in ICS, there's a magnifier that appears over the selection. Anyone know how I can disable that?

[image]

Comment: Could you post a screenshot somewhere of what you are describing as a "magnifier"? I have never seen this on any version of Android, but perhaps I am misunderstanding your use of the term.

Comment: The magnifier is there to make selecting text easier for the user to control. If you change that behavior you make your interface harder to use.

Comment: Which device are you using for tests? In my experience ICS have no magnifier on `EditText` controls. Maybe it's a vendor-customized ICS

Comment: Added screenshot.
@ Devon_C_Mille : I hope you agree it's really in the way and offputting and unnecessary; certainly with the large text I'm using. 
@ mr_archano : It's an ASUS Transformer TF101 running ICS. The application manifest targets Android level 15

Comment: Just Googled this and it's a Transformer specific feature. Any way to change those things and override behaviour?

Comment: I have the same problem in my ASUS zenfone3. Some people reported in below link that it happens in " iPhones, Xperia's, Asus Zenfone and some early HTC phones", but no one reported a way to disable it. 
It's annoying for it slow down the select-text operation.

https://forum.xda-developers.com/x-compact/help/how-to-off-long-press-magnification-t3750924

Answer (score 0):

As of my understanding we can handle **Magnification Gestures** by system settings, We do not have any method to override this functionality/behaviour.

You can refer below links for more about magnification gestures feature:

http://pauljadam.com/androida11y/#magnification

http://static.googleusercontent.com/external_content/untrusted_dlcp/www.google.com/en//help/hc/images/android/android_ug_42/Android-Quick-Start-Guide.pdf

Kindly let me know if i am wrong. Thanks

Comment: Your post is different thing to the post question. The post question needn't triple-tapping, and it occurs at the cursor when selecting text.

Answer (score 0):

After few days I finally found the solution.

I had a problem with a Dialog Window and inside I have an EditText. 
When this magnifier was showing I don't know why but after I closed the Dialog and try to open it again ... it didn't show on the front as usual...it was shown behind of Activity's Window ...strange thing ... I guess is a bug...

The only solution I found for my problem was to set this property to my dialog window:

`LayoutParams lp = dialog.getWindow().getAttributes();
 lp.type = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_PANEL;
 dialog.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);`

and this magnifier tool is not showing anymore on this EditText.

I hope it can help someone.

Comment: This method doesn't work in testing of ASUS zenfone3. The magnifier still appears when selecting text.